# eventlistener not working for dynamically created element

Tags: javascript, html

I have a simple section in which users can add input fields dynamically and users should be able to remove added input fields by clicking the delete button. am using vanilla js

here is a live demo : [demo live codepen](https://codepen.io/makumba/pen/GRORqXp)

HTML

```
<div id="domains-wrapper">
    <div class="input-group">
        <input name="domains" type="text" class="form-control domain-url" placeholder="Type valid url" value="" required="">
        <div class="valid-feedback">Looks good!</div>
        <button id="default-delete" style="display: none;" class="default-delete delete-input-el domain-btn btn-sm border border-1" type="button">
        </button>
        <button id="default-add" class="add-input-el added-input plus-button btn-sm border border-1 add_form_field" type="button">
            <span class="add-icon">+
            </span>
        </button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Js

```
var max_fields = 10;
var wrapper = document.getElementById("domains-wrapper");
var add_button = document.getElementById("default-add");

var x = 1;
add_button.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (x < max_fields) {
        x++;
        $(wrapper).append('<div><input id="delete" type="text" name="mytext[]"/><a href="#" class="delete">Delete</a></div>'); //add input box
    } else {
        alert('You Reached the limits')
    }
})

var deleteBtn = document.querySelectorAll(".delete");

deleteBtn.forEach(function(e) {
    e.addEventListener('click', function() {
        console.log('PL')
      this.parentNode.remove(); //remove the whole div containing input and delete button
    })
});
```

**Problem,** Now when I click the delete button nothing is happening,

Any idea what am I missing here?

Comment: You're not adding any handler to the new element, you're only handling ones that already exist as of when the code is first run. See the linked question's answers, but your best bet here is probably [event delegation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Building_blocks/Events#event_delegation) on `#domains-wrapper`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your are not recovering the .delete to add listener after the click on more button

so delete field don't have listener

I can propose you to add the listener after the field append to solve your situation

```js
    var max_fields = 10;
    var wrapper = document.getElementById("domains-wrapper");
    var add_button = document.getElementById("default-add");

    var x = 1;
    add_button.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        if (x < max_fields) {
            x++;
            var deleteField = document.createElement('div');
            deleteField.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', '<input id="delete" type="text" name="mytext[]"/>');
            var a = document.createElement('a');
            a.href= '#';
            a.innerText = 'Delete';
            a.classList.add('delete');
            deleteField.append(a);
            wrapper.appendChild(deleteField); //add input box
              a.addEventListener('click', function() {
              var target = e.target || e.srcElement;
              console.log('PL')
              deleteField.remove();
           })
        } else {
            alert('You Reached the limits')
        }
    })
```

```html
    <div id="domains-wrapper">
        <div class="input-group">
            <input name="domains" type="text" class="form-control domain-url" placeholder="Type valid url" value="" required="">
            <div class="valid-feedback">Looks good!</div>
            <button id="default-delete" style="display: none;" class="default-delete delete-input-el domain-btn btn-sm border border-1" type="button">
            </button>
            <button id="default-add" class="add-input-el added-input plus-button btn-sm border border-1 add_form_field" type="button">
                <span class="add-icon">+
                </span>
            </button>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Hi this remove everything. needs to remove only the input with delete button and am using vanilla js, thx for help though

Comment: yes sorry i fix the remove line to only delete the clicked line

Comment: i translate the above code in vanilla js

Comment: thanks that is what I needed